# Magento2 provide customer specific PDF document in customer account

Tags: magento2, customer-account, download

In my Magento2 I want to provide a customer specific PDF document for registered customers who purchase certain articles.

1. The customer purchases an article which is actually like a coupon for a  service.
2. After the vendor receives order and payment, he processes the
   service.
3. After the service is done (after a couple of days), the customer should get his personal PDF document for download in his account.

I hope I explained my issue. Can anybody give a hint how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [order PDF](http://store.fooman.co.nz/extensions/magento2/magento-extension-print-order-pdf-m2.html) and [email Attachment](http://store.fooman.co.nz/extensions/magento2/magento-extension-email-attachments-m2.html) extension , it will sender an order PDF as attachment. Customize / override  that PDF to generate Coupon PDF on order success

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I have a PDF document what I get from a third party, so I do not create the PDF myself. I just need to get the customer/order specific Document into the account of the customer.